# Domain name resolution in Android using native programming languages

Tags: android

I'm developing a native application using C/C++.
I need to use name resolution service.
Making JNI calls is an option.
Using an external native library is another option.
However, I'm thinking about the probability of a third option.

As noted [here](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/dns-resolver), on devices running Android 10 and higher, this service is provided with a native library (libnetd_resolv.so).
This means, functions that I need rest in this library and I can confirm [that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/heads/android10-dev/resolv/).

My question is, can I use this library dynamically and get name resolution service?
I know that Android doesn't allow applications to use system libraries but what if I download this shared object and distribute with my application*, does it work?
If it doesn't, is there a future plan for this to work?
I'm asking because it is so weird to me that I need a function, it resides in my hands, but I have to make JNI calls in order to use it.

* When I embed the shared object in my application, there may be some compatibility problems when new updates are made to the shared object but that's not the point for me, if it works for one Android release it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before attempting to add in a third-party library, do check if the existing [Android NDK Networking APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/networking) support your use case.

Do be aware of which versions of Android any particular API is supported.